# Why is my dynamically created asp:table retaining information on Postback?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postback

I have a cart page.
The top lines are the products. 
Then the Subtotal, Shipping, discount, Total lines.

Obviously this is all dynamic.

I call the exact same LoadTable() Sub in my Page_LoadComplete event.

First time around it looks great.
But if I edit the data and postback then it goes crazy:
If I remove a product, and the result is that my table is 1 row shorter.
The last row of the table, instead of showing "TOTAL" and the total amount, it displays what was in the row before the postback (ie. repeating the line before it).

The table is loaded into asp:panel and the beginning of my Sub starts with:

```
pnlCurrentOrder.Controls.Clear()
Dim tblCurrentOrder As Table = New Table()
tblCurrentOrder.Rows.Clear()
```

I have given the Totals Row and cells IDs and when I look at the source, they do have the correct ID information, but they have the wrong data in the cells.

This is very strange to me, Does anyone know whats going on?

Thanks

Comment: why not use a datagrid, or repeater to get what you want. then you just set the .datasource property, perhaps call .databind, and it will display anything in your datasource?

Comment: the short answer, because I have never used them before.

But that doesn't answer my question..
A table that is recreated on every load should not be retaining any data, should it?

Comment: It's really hard to tell without looking at everything. In order to do what you want, you need to fully understand the page lifecycle, and what happens in an ASP.NET page on postback.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You could try moving your code to the Load event. The reason it is probably happening is because server side controls maintain their values between posts be default. You can also try to turn viewstate off for the dynamically generated table.

Comment: I set the EnableViewState to False and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try EnableViewState="false" on your table, to make it not remember the previous values.